# I am trying to use the isEmpty() method and I keep getting an error saying: "Cannot resolve method 'isEmpty'. "

Tags: java

[image: code snippet]
this is my click event. The code is supposed to extract entries from text controls and use it to make calculations. At this stage I m trying to make sure that the user enters all of the values that are required, that is: marks for assignments 1, 2, 3 and the exam mark. I realize that I had not entered the "!" to indicate that the controls should not be empty

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post images of code, but post the code itself using code tags. It is also unclear what type `assing1` is (although I assume a String). If you get compilation errors you probably don't have Java 1.6 or higher but a lower Java version installed (or have your build set to a lower java version which would also make this method unavailable).

Comment: please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/16320675)

Comment: IsEmpty is a String method not a double method. Call it on the String object before deciding to parse it to a dou6

Comment: Thank you. Using them as strings before converting them to doubles worked. Is there a method that does what the isEmpty method does for strings, but to integers and other number types?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanted to do something like this:

```java
        Double assign1;
        String stringAssign1 = mark1.getText().toString();
        if (!stringAssign1.isEmpty()){
            assign1 = Double.parseDouble(stringAssign1);
        }
```

Firstly, you should check if string is empty (also as mentioned before `isEmpty()` is string function), then if not, parse it to double.

Next time please use codeblock instead of screenshot of code :)